# makefile c++ with other h file dependencies with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile

for the life of me I cannot get this to compile properly using a makefile
I have c++ files that are using OpenGL.

Some files are dependent on others

I have 5 files

- main.cpp
- Vector.h
- Vector.cpp
- Utility.cpp
- Utility.h

~ Dependencies ~

IN MAIN.CPP

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "Vector.h"
```

IN VECTOR.CPP

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Utility.h"
```

IN UTILITY.CPP

```
#include "Utility.h"
```

My after trying and arranging various flags this is what
the makefile currently looks like

```
program1: main.o Vector.o Utility.o
    g++ -std=c++11 main.o Vector.o Utility.o -o program1
main.o: main.cpp Vector.h
    g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm
Vector.o: Vector.cpp Vector.h Utility.h
    g++ -std=c++11 Vector.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm
Utility.o: Utility.cpp Utility.h
    g++ -std=c++11 Utility.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm
clean:
    -rm -f *.o
```

Typing "make" outputs the following result:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm
g++ -std=c++11 Vector.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In (.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    makefile:6: recipe for target 'Vector.o' failed
    make: ***[Vector.o] Error 1
```

How can I fix my makefile? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're telling the compiler to link single object files by omitting `-c`
2. You're linking libraries to object files, you only need to link once after all the object files have been compiled
3. Make has built in rules and recipes, use them.

```
objects := main.o Vector.o Utility.o
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11

program1: CC := $(CXX)
program1: LDLIBS := -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm
program1: $(objects)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

main.o: Vector.h
Vector.o: Vector.h Utility.h
Utility.o: Utility.h

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(objects)
```

If you change `main.o` / `main.cpp` to `program1.o` / `program1.cpp` you can further simplify things by getting rid of the `program1` recipe entirely.